# the onclick is not working on first click but works fine after first click

Tags: html, jquery

when the page loads the on click not works first time but then it works fine ,it runs perfect in vs code without onClick() but in visual studio it does not run without onClick() and it runs like this.. please someone guide me about this problem Thanks..

```
<script>
    function GetProductsRowHtmlSlider(product, div) {
        $(div).append($('<div class="column"><div class="container" style="width: 320px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><div class="pic_container"><img src=' + product.imgSrc + ' data-highres=' + product.imgSrc + ' class="image" style="width: 100%; height: auto; padding: 20px;"></div><h3 class="productName" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; overflow-wrap: break-word;">' + product.Title + '</h3><p class="productDisc" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; overflow-wrap: break-word;">' + product.ItemPrice + '</p></div><div id = "myModal" class="modal"><span id="close_model" class="close">&times;</span><img class="modal-content" id="modal-image"></div></div>'))
    }
</script>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
  var len = images.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener("click", openModal);
  }
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

  var modalImg = document.getElementById("modal-image");

  function openModal() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.getAttribute("data-highres");
  }

  var span2 = document.getElementById("close_model");
  span2.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  };

  window.openModal = function (images) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = images.getAttribute("data-highres");
  };
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 320px; height: 530px;">
          <div class="pic_container" onclick="myFunction()">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/de/a5/f1/dea5f10ecf2080ea8e5312ff9fa0db56.jpg" 
data-highres="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/de/a5/f1/dea5f10ecf2080ea8e5312ff9fa0db56.jpg" class="image" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
          </div>
          <h3 class="productName" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;">T-Shirt</h3>
          <p class="productDisc" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;">Threadbare is currently sold in the UK, across Europe, Canada and America</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Close button -->
  <span id="close_model"class="close">&times;</span>
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="modal-image">
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it and add relevant HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work better. If you have jQuery, USE it.

I removed the inline onclick

```js
$(function() {
  const $modal = $('#myModal');
  const $modalImage = $('#modal-image');
  $('.container').on('click', '.image', function() { // assuming .container is STATIC!
    $modalImage.attr('src', $(this).data('highres'));
    $modal.show();
  })
  $('#close_model').on('click', function() {
    $modal.hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="width: 320px; height: 530px;">
  <div class="pic_container">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/de/a5/f1/dea5f10ecf2080ea8e5312ff9fa0db56.jpg" data-highres="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/de/a5/f1/dea5f10ecf2080ea8e5312ff9fa0db56.jpg" class="image" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
  </div>
  <h3 class="productName" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;">T-Shirt</h3>
  <p class="productDisc" style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;">Threadbare is currently sold in the UK, across Europe, Canada and America</p>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Close button -->
  <span id="close_model" class="close">&times;</span>
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="modal-image">
</div>
```

Comment: please see the above code I have edited. Thanks.

Comment: I had a missing `=` I updated my code to match your class

Comment: working perfect in visual studio code but same problem its not working in visual studio

Comment: if I add an onClick() then it works in visual studio but on second click..

Comment: I changed to  `$('.container').on('click', '.image', function() {` but I am assuming that is a STATIC container

Comment: I added the code by which images are inserted in page

Comment: Please. Your HTML does not match the HTML you have in your script. Your classes do not match either.  You have class="container" and "pic_container" and "column_gallary" and so on. How can I help you if you keep showing incomplete code? What div are you passing to `function GetProductsRowHtmlSlider(product, div) {` ? And is THAT div a STATIC div?

Comment: If you cannot give me a static div, then use `$(document).on('click', '.image', function() { `